# The specified message is out of range error

Tags: vb.net, ftp, dbcontext, rebex

I'm getting the following error for a specific email using a POP3 server:

> Rebex.Net.Pop3Exception: The specified message is out of range.

When using:

```
Dim SequenceNumber As Integer = 0
Dim MailMsg As Rebex.Mail.MailMessage = Nothing
Dim UTF8 As New Text.UTF8Encoding
Dim RebexPop3 as new rebex.Net.Pop3
Dim Message As Rebex.Net.Pop3MessageCollection

SequenceNumber = Message.SequenceNumber 
MailMsg = RebexPop3.GetMailMessage(SequenceNumber)
MailMsg.DefaultCharset = UTF8 ' Error generated when filling UTF8
```

Comment: Apparently you aren't passing a valid `SequenceNumber` parameter so look into how you got that number.

Comment: Actually no am passing it correctly , thanks for the note i added how i get the sequence number to my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You never set `Message` to anything so `SequenceNumber` would be nothing or maybe 0. From their example at http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/features/pop3.aspx

```
' get list of all messages
Dim list As Pop3MessageCollection = pop3.GetMessageList(Pop3ListFields.Fast)

' print some info
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} message(s).", list.Count)
For Each info In list
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} [{2}]", info.SequenceNumber, info.UniqueId, info.Length)
Next
```

Once you set `Message` as they did `list`, you would have access to the `SequenceNumber` property of each item in the list as they show in the For Each loop.

Comment: message is being passed as a parameter(in my method not included in this snippet ) it is filled i assure you if it was the case the error would be sequence contains no element , anyway thanks for the effort .